# How to send DBI data in SabreCommandLLSRQ

Tags: xml, wsdl, dbi, sabre

I'm trying to send DBI data in SabreCommandLLSRQ. And it looks like:

```
            TimeStamp=datetime.datetime.now(),
            Request=SCL.Request(HostCommand=f"CK*DBITPA¥ALL¥ССTP41XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX¥PK-123456¥KS-ABCD123", CDATA="true", Output="SCREEN"),
            NumResponses=4,
            ReturnHostCommand=True,
        ).asdict()
```

however, I'm getting a response:
'INVALID DBI ENTRY'[image]

Could you help me investigate, why I'm getting this error